# Running Yii CConsoleCommand on a remote server

Tags: php, yii, ftp, command-line-interface

I have a problem figuring out how make my command work, because I only have access via ftp.

The action is pretty simple:

```
public function actionRun($action = "default") {
    $this->xml = simplexml_load_file('db.xml');
    return $this->{$action}(); // executes the default() method
}
```

All I need is to somehow execute the `php index.php mycommand run`, but I'm lost as to how. This command should only be run once in the life of the whole app.

My question is, is it possible to run such a command? Maybe somehow invoke it through php?

Comment: Check link :http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/91/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii/

Answer (score 0):

Yii command line command are designed to run through Yii.

```
$ cd protected
$ ./yiic --help
$ ./yiic mycommand
```

If you only have ftp access, you may be out of luck, and will have to use some workaround, for example running a cron job, or creating a web page that invokes the last command in the code sample I provided.

```
echo exec('/my_yii_dir/protected/yiic mycommand');
```